# Magento Default contact form is redirecting to 2-column-right layout after the form submission

Tags: magento

I am using default magento contact form in my site.

```
{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

and layout has set to `1 Column`.

When I load the contact form `1 Column` layout is loading. Then I filled the form and click the submit button. Then with the Success message page layout is changing to `2-Column-right` layout.

I need `1 Column` layout after the form submission.

Comment: Check the url? both or urls (before submit and after submit ) are different? if yes then check the controller which is redirecting after success. Else check the layout file for success